# "PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: sendKeysToActiveElement" when sending keys to a form in Selenium2 and PHP

Tags: forms, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, functional-testing, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm doing a PHPUnit driven Selenium2 test case. I'm trying to fill a form.

## Case in which it all runs OK - green bar:

This is the setup:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->setBrowser( 'firefox' );
    $this->setBrowserUrl( 'http://my.nice.project/' );
}
```

With this test case, I get an "ok, green bar":

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $this->url( 'http://my.nice.project/' );

    $element = $this->byTag( 'h5' );
    $this->assertEquals( 'Access to the private area', $element->text() );

    $element = $this->byCssSelector( 'form input[name="email"]' );
    $element->click();
    //$this->keys( 'abc' );
}
```

Note that the `->keys( 'abc' )` is commented out.

Just to test that the toolchain is okey I added a second temporary test:

```
public function testToolchain()
{
    $this->url( 'http://example.com/' );
    $element = $this->byTag( 'p' );

    $this->assertContains( 'illustrative examples in documents', $element->text() );
}
```

As, stated, I get:

```
vagrant@global-functional-tests:/vagrant$ vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 5.7.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 23.02 seconds, Memory: 4.00MB

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

The toolchain is running because if I change the expected text in any of the two tests I get a failure. So necessarily the selenium is launching the firefox, controlling it, getting the page and exploring the content.

## Problem

When I send the keys, with this test (which is the previous one with the line uncommented):

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $this->url( 'http://my.nice.project/' );

    $element = $this->byTag( 'h5' );
    $this->assertEquals( 'Access to the private area', $element->text() );

    $element = $this->byCssSelector( 'form input[name="email"]' );
    $element->click();
    $this->keys( 'abc' );
}
```

I get an exception of type: `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException` => This is the full `phpunit` output:

```
vagrant@global-functional-tests:/vagrant$ vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 5.7.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.E                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 24.24 seconds, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Bibloos\MarmaladeDoughnut\Tests\NewPrivateZoneTest::testLogin
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'global-functional-tests', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-21-generic', java.version: '9-internal'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

/vagrant/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php:165
/vagrant/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php:175
/vagrant/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/CommandsHolder.php:100
/vagrant/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:393
/vagrant/tests/NewPrivateZoneTest.php:48
/vagrant/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:348
/vagrant/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:314

ERRORS!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Errors: 1.
```

Questions:

1. How do I debug what's happening?
2. How do I make that the driver can send keys to the form?
3. Maybe to fill a form I should use a different approach than clicking the element and sending keys?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion - the [PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium) library you used is not up to date with latest changes in Selenium protocol (its also not Selenium 2 any more - the current Selenium version is 3.4.0) and especially with changes in Firefox 48+ and [Geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver).

So I would recommend to go with [facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/) library instead, as it is more maintained and up-to-date with Selenium protocol.

You may also find useful the [lmc-eu/steward](https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward) project, which integrates the php-webdriver library to PHPUnit. Also see the "[Getting started](https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward#getting-started)" section in readme, which explains how to set-up your system to run the Selenium tests in different browsers (or in Docker).